# Flame charts from perf.data

Tags: linux, performance-analysis

After generating a `perf.data` file with `perf record`, Brendan Gregg's excellent [Flamegraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) tool can produce an SVG.

Flamegraphs throw away the time axis and sort samples alphabetically, which is what you want most of the time. However, for periodic features in CPU consumption, we *don't* want to throw away the time axis, and exhibit the temporal data directly. These traces are called flame charts.

What tools are available for visualizing flame charts from `perf.data` files?